# (Drupal twitter module) Adding twitter account used to log in, to that user's twitter accounts list automatically

Tags: drupal, twitter, oauth

I'm using Drupal twitter module with recommended Oauth version(2.02) and I can post to twitter via API successfully. but, I have to manually authenticate the application with the user in /user/%/edit/twitter page.
But I would like to create a fully twitter-integrated web site that automatically add twitter accounts used to log in to the site, to twitter accounts of that user's list.

If somehow I managed to do this, once user log in to site via Twitter can see their own tweets in my site without adding them manually.
But I'm not sure(and looking for your kindly help) how to make this combination.
Drippic.com has already done this. Once logged in, users can tweet without having to add the account again.
I use same twitter application to do both registration and tweet-importing and the application asks for read/write access to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has fixed in later Twitter module's releases. 
If anyone else has this problem, just update to the latest version and you can ditch the problem.